# What unicode characters in the control group other than tab work with MSKLC?

Tags: keyboard-layout, unicode, layout

MSKLC = Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator.
Are there control characters for Home, End, delete, etc. and do they work with MSKLC 1.4?

Answer (score 0):

codes sent by keyboard

47 for (numpad-7/Home), 4F (numpad-1/End), 53 (numpad-./Del)

e0 47 (Grey Home), e0 4f (Grey End), e0 53 (Grey Delete) (keys not in numpad)

however, the keys who have a single function, to give a character or to send a signal to get something done, knowing their control code will be of no use in MSKLC as modifying them will take away their basic function and you will be handicapped how to do that. Say, you define Caps Lock, or Del or Backspace or Tab to something else, then when you need to perform a Caps Lock, or Del or Backspace or Tab, you can't do that because pressing those keys will do the function that you have modified to.

I hope you have already used and exhausted all combination of right Alt, which is called AltGr, because with this key, you get a combination for all keys which can be used without any modifier or with control or with shift or which both ctrl-shift. Thus you get huge possibilities.

Comment: AltGr/Right Alt is equivalent to Alt+Ctrl. Just sayin'...